# Recieve 'object not found' error when using add_pie function from plot_ly package

Tags: r

I used some example code I found online to create multiple pie chart subplots using the plot_ly package - https://plotly.com/r/pie-charts/

However, when I run the code using my dataset, I get the following error:

`Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env) : object 'demo_residence' not found`

The example uses the built-in diamonds dataset in R and works when I run the code. I don't understand why I'm receiving this error because the column 'demo_residence' seems to be there.

Here is my code:

```
results_demo_test <- 
structure(list(demo_residence = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), demo_gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Male", 
"Female"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

fig <- plot_ly()

fig <- fig %>% add_pie(
  count(results_demo_test, demo_residence), labels = ~demo_residence, values = ~n, 
  name = "Residence", domain = list(row = 0, column = 0))

fig <- fig %>% add_pie(
  count(results_demo_test, demo_gender), labels = ~demo_gender, values = ~n, 
  name = "Gender", domain = list(row = 0, column = 1))

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Pie Charts with Subplots", showlegend = F,grid=list(rows=1, columns=1),
  xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
  yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
  )

fig
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
fig <- plot_ly()

fig <- fig %>% add_pie(data = 
  count(results_demo_test, demo_residence), labels = ~demo_residence, values = ~n, 
  name = "Residence", domain = list(row = 0, column = 0))

fig <- fig %>% add_pie(data = 
  count(results_demo_test, demo_gender), labels = ~demo_gender, values = ~n, 
  name = "Gender", domain = list(row = 0, column = 1))

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Pie Charts with Subplots", showlegend = F,grid=list(rows=1, columns=1),
  xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
  yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
)

fig
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work when specify data.

```
fig <- plot_ly()

fig <- fig %>% add_pie(data = results_demo_test,
  count(results_demo_test, demo_residence), labels = ~demo_residence, values = ~n, 
  name = "Residence", domain = list(row = 0, column = 0))

fig <- fig %>% add_pie(data = results_demo_test,
  count(results_demo_test, demo_gender), labels = ~demo_gender, values = ~n, 
  name = "Gender", domain = list(row = 0, column = 1))

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Pie Charts with Subplots", showlegend = F,grid=list(rows=1, columns=1),
  xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
  yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
)

fig
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That didn't quite work, but turns out I did need the "data =" before my count() function.